# Why don't simple \newcommand shorthand produce the same result?

Tags: macros, text, text-decorations

When I was working on a note for linear algebra, I noticed that I used `\textbf{v}` a lot, so I put

`\newcommand{\vecv}{\textbf{v}}`

at the top of the document.

But I noticed that when using it in paragraph, `\vecv` does not produce the correct spacing

[image: bold v that does not space right]

But using `\textbf{v}` works just fine

[image: bold v that space just fine]

Now why is that?

Comment: LaTeX commands that doesn't accept arguments (like the one you've defined) eats the following space. Try `\vecv{}` instead or `{\vecv}`

Comment: So there's no way to just do it like that without the braces?

Comment: @DaVarPhi  see the xspace package, although it has some caveats.

Comment: Off-topic: Assuming that `\vecv` is supposed to represent a math-y object, the macro definition `\newcommand{\vecv}{\textbf{v}}` is wrong. Better would be `\newcommand{\vecv}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{v}}}`, where `\ensuremath` is a macro provided by the [amsmath](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package.

Comment: If something has math meaning, put it into math mode (`$... $`, this gives the doc a better structure)

Comment: @Mico `\ensuremath` is actually from latex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks for correcting my mistake.

Comment: @DaVarPhi in practice this is rarely a problem because the space isn't needed in math mode and in text it is better to use `$\vecv$` so again there is no problem to solve. Rather than define lots of such commands I would define `\vec` to be `\mathbf` and use `\vec{v}` so it is usable with all letters and again has no problem with spaces.